# Setting values when iterating through a DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dictionary of states (example IA:Idaho). I have loaded the dictionary into a DataFrame `bystate_df`.

then I am importing a CSV with states deaths that I want to add them to the `bystate_df` as I read the lines:

```
byState_df = pd.DataFrame(states.items())
byState_df['Deaths'] = 0
df['Deaths'] = df['Deaths'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
print byState_df
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Area'] in states:
           byState_df[(byState_df[0] == row['Area'])]['Deaths'] = row['Deaths']         

print byState_df
```

but the `byState_df` is still 0 afterwords:

```
      0                         1  Deaths
 0   WA                Washington       0
 1   WI                 Wisconsin       0
 2   WV             West Virginia       0
 3   FL                   Florida       0
 4   WY                   Wyoming       0
 5   NH             New Hampshire       0
 6   NJ                New Jersey       0
 7   NM                New Mexico       0
 8   NA                  National       0
```

I test `row['Deaths']` while it iterates and it's producing the correct values, it just seem to be setting the `byState_df` value incorrectly.

Comment: I think it's because you use chained slice in `byState_df[(byState_df[0] == row['Area'])]['Deaths']` so that you are actually setting some values on a copy rather than the actual `df`.

Comment: The first index `[...==...]` is advanced indexing, and produces a copy.  Indexing with `['Deaths']` first might work, since it returns a view of one of the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following code where I use `.loc` instead of `[][]`.

```
byState_df = pd.DataFrame(states.items())
byState_df['Deaths'] = 0
df['Deaths'] = df['Deaths'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
print byState_df
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Area'] in states:
           byState_df.loc[byState_df[0] == row['Area'], 'Deaths'] = row['Deaths']         

print byState_df
```